# Programmatically hover Material Form Field in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, hover

I have an outline [`MatFormField`](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview) like this:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <input matInput ...>
</mat-form-field>
```

It shows a nice outline when hovered.

I want to create the same hovering outline effect on this element but programmatically while the user hovers another element on the page.

Is it possible to create the hover effect without actually hovering the element?

What I tried:

- I know how to programmtically `focus()` the input. That is however not what I want.
- I tried to [trigger a built-in mouseenter/mouseover-event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events). That seemed not to work however.
- Re-applying the styles used by angular (e.g. with `ng-deep` or similar) is not an option as these might change with updates.

Answer (score 2):

One simple approach is to capture the mouseover event on the "another element on the page" and change the target's element style

html

```
<input (mouseover)="hover(true)" (mouseout)="hover(false)" />

<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <input matInput id="myInput" />
</mat-form-field>
```

and using a simple function

```
  hover(hover) {
    document.getElementById('myInput').style['border-color'] = hover
      ? 'red'
      : 'black';
  }
```

Comment: Technically that would work, but angular does not expose those styles readily. (The styling might break on angular updates, e.g.) so I can't accept it as an answer.

Comment: This is the only option you have tough @vlz